# Set Search Filter Panel to Always Display

Tags: javascript, html, search, filter, show

I am working on editing search functionality for a knowledge base. The knowledge base has a filter panel that can be displayed where users can select which database or category they want to use to filter search results. Currently it is set to "hidden" until the link/icon is clicked on for it. I would like to make it always visible if possible. Below I have the script file, css file, and html for the search and filter section. I would like for the show/hide link/icon to still work. I just want the default to be that the filter pane is shown.

```js
//Link function
function(scope,element,attr){
 if(scope.data.set_foccus)
 setTimeout(function(){
  element.find('#kb_search_input').focus();
 },0);
 
 var c = scope.c;
 $rootScope = $injector.get("$rootScope");
 
 c.showFiltersButton = true;
 
 c.showAndHideFilters = function(){
  if(c.showFiltersButton==true){
   $(".hide-filters").addClass("show-filters").removeClass("hide-filters");
   $(".expand-width").addClass("original-width").removeClass("expand-width");
   c.showFiltersButton = false;
  }else{
   $(".show-filters").addClass("hide-filters").removeClass("show-filters");
   $(".original-width").addClass("expand-width").removeClass("original-width");
   c.showFiltersButton = true;
  }
 }
 
 c.hideFilters = function(){
   $(".show-filters").addClass("hide-filters").removeClass("show-filters");
  $(".original-width").addClass("expand-width").removeClass("original-width");
  c.showFiltersButton = true;
 }
 
 c.toggleFacets = function(){
  $rootScope.showFacet = !$rootScope.showFacet;
  $rootScope.showLanguageFacet = false;
 }
 
 c.showLanguageFacet = function(){
  $rootScope.showFacet = !$rootScope.showFacet;
  $rootScope.showLanguageFacet = true;
 }
 
 c.keywordChanged = function(event){
  c.keyword = c.keyword.trim();

  if(c.keyword != c.oldKeyword){
   //handle keyboard events for enter and keyup
   if(event){
    var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
    if(!c.data.allow_instant_search && keycode != 13)
     return;
   }

   //throw update event based on options   
   if( (c.data.allow_empty_search && c.keyword == "") || (c.keyword && c.keyword.length >= c.data.min_search_char)){
    $rootScope.$emit('sp.kb.updated.keyword',{'keyword':c.keyword});
    c.hideFilters();
   }

   c.oldKeyword = angular.copy(c.keyword);
  }

  scope.$evalAsync(function(){
   if($("#kb_search_input"))
    $("#kb_search_input").focus();
  });
 };

 //If instant search enable then wait for 200ms for the next input then throw event
 $("#kb_search_input").keyup(_.debounce(function(event){
  c.keywordChanged(event);
 },c.options.search_wait));

 $(window).resize(function() {
  var width1 = $(window).width();
  if(width1<=992 && !$rootScope.isMobile){
   $rootScope.isMobile = true;
  }else if(width1>992 && $rootScope.isMobile ){
   $rootScope.showFacet = false;
   $rootScope.isMobile = false;
  }
 });
 
 //set keyword onload from url and throw event
 if(c.data.keyword){
  c.keyword = c.data.keyword;
  c.keywordChanged();
 }
}
```

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 991px) {
    .kb-search-block {
      padding-top : 7px !important;
    }
    .filter-icon-padding {
      padding-left : 0px !important;
      padding-right : 0px !important;
      text-align : center;
    }
    .kb-search-display-none {
      display :none !important;
    }
    .kb-search-block .lang-icon {
      font-size : 18px;
      float :left;
      padding-right:9px;
    }
  }
   @media only screen and (min-width:991px) {
   .expand-width {
     width :100%;
    }
    .hide-filters {
     display :none;
    }
    .original-width{
     width : 75%;
    }
    .show-filters {
     display:block;
    }
 }
```

```html
<div class="kb-search-block" ng-class="$root.showFacet? 'kb-search-display-none':''" ng-cloak>
  <div class="search-bar col-md-5 col-xs-11 col-sm-7 no-pad">

    <div ng-if="c.showLanguageIcon" class="visible-xs visible-sm lang-icon">
      <span ng-click ="::c.showLanguageFacet()"><i class="fa fa-globe icon-padding" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
    </div>
    <div class="pad-bottom">
      <div class="input-group input-group-{{::c.options.size}}">
        <input id="kb_search_input" name="q" type="text" ng-model="c.keyword" aria-label="{{::options.title}}"  placeholder="{{::options.title}}" class="form-control">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
          <button name="search" type="submit" aria-label="search" class="btn btn-{{::c.options.color}}" ng-click="c.keywordChanged('')">
            <i ng-if="::c.options.glyph" class="fa fa-{{::c.options.glyph}}"></i>
          </button>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="filter-icon-padding visible-xs visible-sm col-xs-1 col-sm-1">
    <span class=" filter-icon" ng-click ="::c.toggleFacets()" ng-class="c.applycolor ? 'selected-filter-color' : 'filter-color'" ><i class="fa fa-filter filter-size" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <span class="check-position" ng-show="c.applycolor"><i class="fa fa-check float-left"  aria-hidden="true"></i></span></span>
  </div>
  
  <!--
 <div class="visible-xs visible-sm col-xs-1 col-sm-1 no-pad">
    <div class="col-xs-11 col-sm-11 pad-bottom no-pad">
-->
  <div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="hidden-xs hidden-sm filter-class">
   <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="showFilterBtn"  ng-click="c.showAndHideFilters()"><i class="fa fa-list" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <span ng-show="c.showFiltersButton" class="filter-text">${Show filters}</span>
    <span ng-show="!c.showFiltersButton" class="filter-text">${Hide filters}</span></a>
  </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

```js
//client script
function($rootScope,$window,$timeout,KnowledgeSearchService,$scope) {
 var c = this;


 
 c.keyword = c.data.keyword || "";
 c.oldKeyword = c.data.keyword || "";
 c.options.glyph = c.options.glyph || 'search';
 c.filterCount =0;
 c.applycolor =false;
 c.items =[];
 c.showLanguageIcon = false;
 if($rootScope.showLanguageIcon){
  c.showLanguageIcon = $rootScope.showLanguageIcon;
 }
 var qry;

 //Subscribe search element to service on load
 if(KnowledgeSearchService){
  var input = {};
  input.element = "search";
  input.alt_url_params = c.options.alt_search_url_params;
  KnowledgeSearchService.subscribe(input);
 }
 var refreshSearchFilter = $rootScope.$on('sp.kb.refresh.filter',function (event,data){
  if(data){
   c.items = data;
  }
  if(c.items.length>0){
   c.filterCount = c.items.length;
   c.applycolor = true;
  }else{
   c.filterCount = 0;
   c.applycolor = false;
  }
 });


 var refreshKeyword = $rootScope.$on('sp.kb.refresh.keyword',function(event,data){
  if(data)
   c.keyword = data.keyword;     
 });
 
 $scope.$on('$destroy',function(){
  refreshSearchFilter();
  refreshKeyword();
 });
```

```js
//Server script
(function($sp) {

 options.alt_search_url_params = options.alt_search_url_params || "";

 //Set keyword from url
 data.keyword = "";
 var keywordParm = $sp.getParameter('query') || "";

 if(keywordParm == ""){
  if(options.alt_search_url_params){
   var qParams =  options.alt_search_url_params.toString().split(",");
   qParams.forEach(function(key){
    if($sp.getParameter(key))
     keywordParm = $sp.getParameter(key);
   });
  }
 }
 
 if(keywordParm)
  data.keyword = keywordParm;

 //set values based on options and properties.
 //options will be given precedence if value exit
 data.set_foccus = gs.getProperty('glide.knowman.portal_search_focus') == 'true' || false;
 data.min_search_char = parseInt(options.min_search_char || gs.getProperty('glide.knowman.search_character_limit') || 3);
 data.allow_instant_search = options.allow_instant_search ? (options.allow_instant_search == 'Use system property' ?  gs.getProperty('glide.knowman.search.instant_results') == 'true' : options.allow_instant_search == 'Yes') : gs.getProperty('glide.knowman.search.instant_results') == 'true' || false;
 data.allow_empty_search = options.allow_empty_search ? (options.allow_empty_search == 'Use system property' ?  gs.getProperty('glide.knowman.allow_empty_search') == 'true' : options.allow_empty_search == 'Yes') : gs.getProperty('glide.knowman.allow_empty_search') == 'true' || false;
 
 options.search_wait = options.search_wait || 500;
 options.title = options.title || gs.getMessage('Search (minimum {0} characters)',data.min_search_char+'');

 var langOption = {};
 langOption.alt_lang_url_params = options.alt_lang_url_params || "";
 data.language_picker = $sp.getWidget("kb-language-picker",langOption);
})($sp);
```

Comment: You can remove the css `display: none`.

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem. The link for show/hide is still active, but when `display: none` is removed the filter pane appears above the search results instead of beside them and the user can still click the show/hide link, but all it does now is switch between search results being below the pane and being beside the pane. I want the show/hide to still work. I just want the default to be that the filter pane is visible, but can still be hidden if the user chooses.

Comment: When the user clicks on the Filter link, this code runs ```$(".hide-filters").addClass("show-filters").removeClass("hide-filters");```. ```.hide-filters``` selector is not present in your html. How is that class being added to your filter pane?

Comment: @gillharman I've added two more snippets to the post (Client & Server scripts). That is all that I have, but I don't see anything in those snippets that would be calling the `.hide-filters` class in the filter pane. I'm not real fluent in scripting languages. Pretty much all of this was provided by the system for the knowledge base. I'm just hoping to figure out how to edit the "show/hide" functionality.

Comment: Based on the css, ```.hide-filters``` and ```.show-filters``` are only applied when ```min-width > 991px```. Depending on if you are actually working with small devices, ```c.toggleFacets``` might the correct function that executes when you click the show/hide filter icon/link. Are you clicking a _Show Filters_ / _Hide Filters_ link or a filter icon?

Comment: It's a _Show Filters / Hide Filters_ link on a full size screen then it turns into a filter icon when the window/screen shrinks small enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your Link Function, right between **c.showFiltersButton = true;** and **c.showAndHideFilters**:

```
$(".hide-filters").addClass("show-filters").removeClass("hide-filters");
$(".expand-width").addClass("original-width").removeClass("expand-width");
```

Comment: Thanks! That does what I was looking for. I also had to comment out `c.showFiltersButton = true;` because the filter was automatically showing but the link/button still said "Show Filters". Once I commented that out after adding your suggestion, everything worked perfectly.